# xamarin upload file (image or pdf) to server and delete file from server

Tags: xamarin.android

How to upload any file (image or pdf) to server and delete file from server by xamarin android.

any idea to do that

Thanks advanced.

Comment: up any idea please

Comment: Which server? Didn't you get any api from server side?

Comment: asp.net server. Could you help me about that or give me any idea please?

Comment: Sorry, no, it based on your server.

Comment: any idea to do that .....!

Comment: I am waiting ... up

Comment: This is quite an unclear question since we don't know how did you implement in your server side, usually in Android client side, we can use Http to post request to/ get response from your server. You may refer to [Android – Upload files to ASP.NET Web API service](http://hintdesk.com/android-upload-files-to-asp-net-web-api-service/), by android side, it's Java code, but you can try to convert it to c# for xamarin.